# Problema con firebase Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data

Tags: javascript, firebase

Me encuentro haciendo un chat utilizando Firebase y JS.

En la ultima funcion que agrege, tendria que almacenar los mensajes enviados a la base de datos (Si no entiendo mal el tutorial por el que me guio). Al hacerlo, me salen los siguientes errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La funcion es la siguiente:

```
    const contenidoChat = (user) = () => {

    formulario.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(contenidoChat.value)
         if(!inputChat.value.trim()){
             console.log('texto vacio')
             return
        }
        firebase.firestore().collection('chat').add({
            texto: inputChat.value,
            uid: user.uid,
            fecha: Date.now()

        }).then(res => {console.log('texto agregado')})
        .catch( e=> console.log(e))
    })
}
```

Comment: Segun lo veo, deberias tener el campo de texto en string, el de uid en string, y el de fecha en timestamp en firestore, asi los tienes?

Comment: Si, asi es como los tengo @PacManProgramador

Comment: Y ya verificaste que user.uid te devuelva lo que quieres correctamente?, Si no verificalo con console.log(user.uid)

Comment: Tanto el contenido del chat, como el user uid aparece como indefinido en consola @PacManProgramador

Comment: Entonces ese es el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay 2 posibles cosas que te generen el error

1.-

Cambia

```
const contenidoChat = (user) = () => {
```

Por

```
const contenidoChat = (user) => {
```

2.- Posiblemente no estas enviando la variable user correctamente

Comment: Me sirvio, muchas gracias!